# GCM API Key confusion

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use GCM for my project and so i create a project at google console and wanted to add an api key. Now i have different options:

1. Server Key
2. Browser Key
3. Android Key
4. iOS Key

What i actually want to do is sending GCM Messages from my Apache Server using PHP to my Android devices. So which kind of key do i need now? The Server Key? The Browser Key or the Android Key?

I know that all i need at my Android Client side is the `SENDER_ID` which is the id of my project. I just need the API key serverside.

Comment: you need `Server Key` for your php side.

Comment: So the android key is only if i want to send a gcm message from my android device to somewhere?

Comment: You dnt need of android key to send message. you only require `serverkey` and `register key` which you will get after u register you device with GCM server(by calling `register()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **Server Key**. Using it you can send push notifications to Android Devices using `cURL` in `PHP`.

Answer (score 1):

Check official web site: [Setting up API keys](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490)

Comment: Thank you. But it is still confusing because they write "Use this key if your application runs on Android" and "Use this key if your application runs on a Server" they dont mention where the gcm is sended from and thats the important part. because from my logical way of thinking i have an application for the server AND for android. So which key to use is still the question after reading the official website.

Comment: you re right. here they tell to use server api key:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start 

"Also, copy the Server API key. Before running the app, you'll need to add this as the value of API_KEY in GcmSender.java."