# GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) returns suddenly 401

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is there any reason why the [GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) Service from Google suddenly returns a 401 for a request to send an Android push notification? The call looks like this

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=<my_android_key>" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"/topics/my_topic\", \"data\":{\"category\":\"help\", \"title\":\"Test\", \"text\":\"Test\", \"param\":\"\"}}"
```

The result is

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

UPDATE:

Google names four possible [causes for this error](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes):

- Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax in HTTP request.
- Invalid project number sent as key
- Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
- Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs.

I checked the validity of the API key in question [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#checkAPIkey), and it seems to be invalid. The question is why? It used to work so far. Argh. :-/

Comment: API keys changed / deleted? also, maybe add some code that shows the request.

Comment: We accidentally deleted the account and restored it a bit later, could this make the token invalid? :-/ Not sure.

Comment: Maybe try creating a new Server API key for the project that the GCM Service is enabled for.

Comment: Just put in your app new API key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why sending push notifications using the **Android Key** stopped working, since it used to work before. I managed to send a Push Notification to an Android app by using the **Server key** instead of the **Android key** like this:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=<my_server_key>" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"/topics/my_topic\", \"data\":{\"category\":\"help\", \"title\":\"Test\", \"text\":\"Test\", \"param\":\"\"}}"
```

Apparently this seems to be the correct method now for Android:
[Why Android key (api key) is invalid or that key is deprecated by GCM server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776778/why-android-key-api-key-is-invalid-or-that-key-is-deprecated-by-gcm-server)

I found a site which says that "Google made a change that stopped Android Keys from working for GCM/FCM for security reasons"
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/4lCPr-UIuY0/ShWZk6z2AAAJ

So the answer seems to be to use the "Server Key" to send Android GCM messages (not the "Android Key").

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you were not use server key from developer console for your application.